# jquery animated menu: how to get active state

Tags: javascript, jquery

please can you help a jquery beginner out? I don't really know how to go ahead...

I did a jquery animated menu: [look at this](http://bern09.ch/j04_test). the content loads with ajax, so there's not really a page load.

now i have to do the active item part. to give a clicked item a class "on", I did this:

```
$navig.click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("on");
    $navig.not(this).removeClass("on");
})
```

the item with class "on" has to:

- animate to active state (similar to the mouseover state), and keep this
- other items has to animate back to the normal state (when class "on" is removed)
- if you click on a sub item, the parent item has to animate to active state

any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the `:animated' selector

```
$navig.click(function() {
    // turn on current item and animate to blablabla
    $(this).addClass("on").animate({blablabla});
    // turn off others and animate back
    $navig.not(this).removeClass("on").filter(':animated').stop().animate({blablabla});
});
```

Comment: thank you, it solves the problem. didn't know the :animated thing. 
my last issue is, how to give a parent item the class "on", when you click on its child (subNav), any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might get somewhere with CSS animation, like this:

```
.menuitem { transition: all 1s ease-in-out; }
```

Support is not very good right now, I'm pretty sure. For Webkit-based browsers it works but with the

```
-webkit-transition
```

property instead of `transition`. Maybe there's similar support for other browsers.

Comment: Yes, I know this css3 feature. But unfortunely it has to work for all browsers... thank you Grumdrig